# ATMega32, PetitFS, writing measurements to file

Tags: avr, programming

I'm trying to write measurements from external sensor to the file (lets say 1 per second). I'm using ATMega32 and PetitFS. At this moment I'm able to write one measure:

```
int main(void){

    BYTE result;
    WORD s1;

    for(;;){
        sprintf(buff, "Measure: %d\r\n", mes);
        s1=4;
        result = pf_write(buff, sizeof(buff), &s1);
        write_close();
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to extend above code with pf_lseek to append another measure after previous one. Can someone give me a hint/suggestion how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not post the whole code, as `pf_mount` and `pf_open` are also needed to get started.

First of all - just don't close the file, call `pf_write` again with another sample.

Second - if you want to append to an existing file - open the file with `pf_open` and then try `pf_lseek` perhaps with a very high number (`UINT32_MAX`). I think that it will just set the pointer to the end of the file (check the error code).